# Fetching a blob from database as a byte[] using myBatis

Tags: spring, mybatis

I am using spring MyBatis 1.2.0 in a project, where I have a query that gets data from a BLOB field in an Oracle 11g database. I want to retrieve the field as a byte array (byte[]), my Code is:

```
<select id="getResponse" resultType="_byte[]" parameterType="string">
   select blob_Data from Table where id = #{value,jdbcType=VARCHAR} AND ROWNUM = 1    
</select>
```

This is giving following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B incompatible with [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.convertToArray(MapperMethod.java:136)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:119)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:58)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:43)
```

Apart from this, I have also tried using resultMap:

```
<resultMap id="responseMap" type="ResponseMessageModel">
    <result property="blobData" column="blob_Data"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getResponse" resultMap="responseMap" parameterType="string">
   select blob_Data from table where id = #{value,jdbcType=VARCHAR} AND ROWNUM = 1    
</select>
```

and also specifying the javaType:

```
<resultMap id="responseMap" type="ResponseMessageModel">
      <result property="blobData" javaType="_byte[]" column="blob_Data"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getResponse" resultMap="responseMap" parameterType="string">
   select blob_Data from table where id = #{value,jdbcType=VARCHAR} AND ROWNUM = 1    
</select>
```

but with no luck, all give the same ClassCastException

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to specify a JDBC type in your result map:

```xml
<result property="blobData" column="blob_Data" jdbcType="BLOB"/>
```

Here an example from Camunda BPM:

[Mapping with result map "resourceResultMap", that contains a bytes property](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/resources/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/mapping/entity/Resource.xml)

[Entity with bytes (byte[]) field](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/impl/persistence/entity/ResourceEntity.java)

**Edit:**

If it is not working, please have a look at following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059872/how-to-select-a-blob-column-from-database-using-ibatis). It suggests to use **BINARY** as JDBC type or to use a custom type handler like in the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried this but now I am getting a null from the database, but the BLOB column contains some value.

Answer (score 2):

So, I got this to work by making the following changes in my code-

I am using a resultMap and specified both javaType and jdbcType:

```
<resultMap id="responseMap" type="ResponseMessageModel">
      <result property="blobData" javaType="_byte[]" column="blob_Data" jdbcType="BLOB"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getResponse" resultMap="responseMap" parameterType="string">
   select blob_Data from table where id = #{value,jdbcType=VARCHAR} AND ROWNUM = 1    
</select>
```

By doing this, I am able to successfully retrieve the BLOB value as a byte[].

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in my query to fetch the blob column value as a string

```
UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(BLOB_COLUMN_NAME, 200,1)) FAX_NOTES
```

This maps the blob to a string and mybatis has:

```xml
<result column="FAX_NOTES" property="faxNotes"  jdbcType="BLOB" />
```

In the java class -

```java
private String faxNotes;
```