# How to read image data to jsp from sybase?

Tags: java, database, jsp, sybase, mybatis

I'm facing problem on reading image data from sybase.

#### Error querying database.  Cause: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Error; - nested throwable: (java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The method com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybResultSet.getBlob(String) is not supported and should not be called.)

I'm using Mybatis mapper.xml to insert/select data with jdbcType="BLOB",  in sybase it's image type. In the java file getting the binary data with response.getOutputStream().write(obj.getBinary()); however, it doesn't work and throws Unsupported exception.
any idea is appreciated.

Comment: Check here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670078/fetching-a-blob-from-database-as-a-byte-using-mybatis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28670078/fetching-a-blob-from-database-as-a-byte-using-mybatis).

Comment: Thanks. we have same config in the xml. But we are using Sybase as database to store binary data. No issue in sqlserver but it's not work on Sybase.

Comment: upgrade jdbc driver to jconn4.jar to support getBlob(String), issue is solved.